# How to set value of java bean property in JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl, javabeans

I use this java bean in a JSP file:

```
<jsp:useBean scope='session' id='project' class='org.sail.biometria.bean.manageproject.ProjectBean' />
```

and I have this boolean variable:

```
${project.projectParameterConfig.ForcedChange}
```

I have tried to change the value from true to false with this code:

```
<c:set var="project.projectParameterConfig.ForcedChange" value="false"/>
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

The `<c:set var>` sets/overrides a variable in given EL scope. You don't need it here. You need to specify the bean instance in `<c:set target>` and the desired property name in `<c:set property>`.

```
<jsp:useBean id="bean" class="com.example.Bean" />
<c:set target="${bean}" property="someProperty" value="newvalue" />
```

An alternative is to use `<jsp:setProperty>`, this works basically the same way, only the `name` must refer the bean name, not the bean itself.

```
<jsp:useBean id="bean" class="com.example.Bean" />
<jsp:setProperty name="bean" property="someProperty" value="newvalue" />
```

Comment: How should I call a function from value attribute of bean in above example?